# Creating a b2body for sprite in box2d

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Following the [tutorial for the breakout game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/28604/how-to-create-a-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-2-x-tutorial-part-1) I've created 3 sprites with their own bodies - ball and 2 paddles. My question might be very simple so sorry, I'm still learning. Anyway, my problem is unlike in the example, my sprites are scaled i.e.:

```
-(id)init {
    p1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1.png"];
    p1.position = ccp(160, winSize.height * 0.08);
    p1.scaleX = 190 / 2 / p1.contentSize.width;
    p1.scaleY = 58 / 2 / p1.contentSize.height;

    b2BodyDef p1BodyDef;
    p1BodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    p1BodyDef.position.Set(160/PTM_RATIO, 40/PTM_RATIO);
    p1BodyDef.userData = p1;
    _p1Body = _world->CreateBody(&p1BodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape p1Shape;
    p1Shape.SetAsBox(p1.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, p1.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);

    b2FixtureDef p1ShapeDef;
    p1ShapeDef.shape = &p1Shape;
    p1ShapeDef.density = 0.3f;
    p1ShapeDef.friction = 1.0f;
    p1ShapeDef.restitution = 0.0f;
    _p1Fixture = _p1Body->CreateFixture(&p1ShapeDef);
}
```

After creating the body, I created an update method which detect the collision between my paddle and ball using the contact listener. This works okay however, I noticed while testing the game that there are instances wherein the ball bounces even though it hasn't collided with the actual sprite's position like around 2-3cm off for both the top and sides of the paddle. I suspect that this is because the shape of my polygon and the scale-x and -y of my sprite are different. So my question is, how can I set the body's size to be the same as the scaled sprite? I tried something like:

```
p1Shape.SetAsBox(190 / 2 / p1.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2, 58 / 2 / p1.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2);
```

But the collision was ignored as if the body wasn't there at all. So how do I make the b2body of my paddle the same size of the paddle sprite if it's been scaled?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think I figured it out after some more research. Here's how I set the shape of the body:

```
p1Shape.SetAsBox(p1.contentSize.width/PTM_RATIO/2 * p1.scaleX, p1.contentSize.height/PTM_RATIO/2 * p1.scaleY);
```

I can't say for certain that this is the correct solution since I don't have debug draw enabled and I can't figure out just yet how to make it work but judging from the collisions after trying to run some tests on my game, this seems like it fixed my problem. If there's anybody else who might think there's a more correct way of doing this, please let me know. Thanks